# multiple actions specified in task ansible "include vars" and "templates"

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am facing this specific error while executing my play. I have a roles directory where I have tasks and vars folder. Below is the main.yml under roles/appconfig/tasks

```
---
 - name: create templates
   include_vars:
     - dev.yml
   template:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /my-ansible-v2/my-properties/{{ item | basename | regex_replace('\.j2$', '') }}
   with_fileglob:
         - /roles/appconfig/templates/*.j2
```

I need to load the variable definition file from /vars folder so i have included "include_vars". I know in a single task you can only specify one action but is there any other way to achieve this?

ERROR - ** multiple actions specified in task ansible "include vars" and "templates" **

Please let me know if someone can help

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above item is that you're running 2 actions in a single task. To fix, split the `include_vars` action from the `template` action in your file:

```
  - name: load variables
    include_vars:
      - dev.yml
  - name: create templates
    template:
    ...
```

Note: the error message is very precise in this case (not always true for Ansible)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I was able to make it work by defining dev.yml at play level under group_vars.